# How do you temporarily hide the output of a bash script that is running?

Tags: linux, bash, rhel

This question may or may not have been asked already, I couldn't find it anywhere & I'm a bit of a Linux beginner.

I got a ./start.sh script that runs on my RHEL 4 server and sends out trace outputs every other second. Example: Trace: Server Running on alias 1, 2 etc... it's there to make sure the server didn't drop out.

I need to run some of my DDoS protection tools and scanners as this is running all at the same time. Though I can't ever see what's going on because of all the trace output!

How would I go about temporarily disabling output as it is ALREADY running, while keeping it running in the background then running my tools and then when I'm done re-enabling the output again?

Comment: This is off-topic for SO, but use `Ctrl-z` to stop the job, then `bg` to background it. Then use `fg` to bring it back into the foreground again when you wish to see the messages again.

Comment: actually putting it in the bg won't stop the messages from being sent to the current terminal.

Comment: Ctrl+Z doesn't seem to stop the job. When I type bg it says "bg: current: no such job" when I type jobs it shows nothing, but yet I still get the trace output. Each of my scripts all have & to them, so it's quite confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two solutions:

- use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) (preferably), or
- use redirection and `tail`.

For example:

```
$ stdbuf -oL ./start.sh > /tmp/start.sh.log &
$ tail -f /tmp/start.sh.log
```

After doing this, you can see the log messages in your terminal. You can kill `tail` with impunity and start it again whenever you want to see the messages. When the log file gets too big, you can shorten it to zero with:

```
$ echo -n > /tmp/start.sh.log
```

Bash's redirect can seamlessly handle the file suddenly getting truncated. Not sure if this is true for all shells. You can interpose `tee` if that becomes a problem with your shell.

I added the `stdbuf -oL` to “encourage” the shell-script to line-buffer `stdout`. Any commands in there that buffer their own output won't be affected, but it might help.

Comment: I tried out that redirection & tail but it didn't seem to work.

All of my scripts are like... 
cd /home/game1/game
./gameserver gameserver.conf gameserveralias.conf> game1.log &
sleep 16

The game server is a java/c# program made for linux, not sure what all it consist of but it's the one sending trace messages, which I don't want to get rid of, just want to hide for a minute.

I'm going to try screen, I really appreciate all the help. I'll tell you how it goes & will accept your answer if it works. Thank you.

Comment: Try to redirect both stdout and stderr, like `./start.sh >& /tmp/start.log` or `./start.sh > /tmp/start.log 2>&1`

Comment: RHEL4 is really old, but there are still *screen* RPMs out there, e.g.: https://packages.endpoint.com/rhel/4/os/i386/screen-4.0.2-6.i386.rpm

Comment: @Siqko: it's probably a buffering issue. I'm updating the answer to account for it.

Comment: For some reason it's saying that stdbuf isn't a command. RHEL4 issue? Thanks for all the help you have provided me. My RPM's don't seem to work, gonna run WinSCP on it & try it that way.

Comment: @Siqko, you're probably right: the version of GNU coreutils on RHEL4 probably predates the addition of `stdbuf`.